# IBM MobileFirst v8 trying to obtain Token on android cordova app after successful login challenge handler

Tags: android, cordova, oauth-2.0, ibm-mobilefirst

- App: cordova application
- platform :android
- mfp server    :8.0.0.00-20170124-152449
- mfp-plugin :8.0.2017013103
- android cordova build    :6.1.2

  {"status":400,"statusText":"Bad Request","responseText":"{\"errorCode\":\"invalid_client\",\"errorMsg\":\"Incorrect JWT format\"}","errorMsg":"Incorrect JWT format","errorCode":"invalid_client"}

Comment: Uninstall the app and re-install, it should work fine.

Comment: Did, but unfortunately still not working.

Comment: At what point exactly, do you get this error? You mention successful login.Do you see the error during obtainAccessToken() ? If you were to try this sample :https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/quick-start/cordova/
do you see the same issue?

Comment: Is this intermittent or reproducible at will?

Comment: yes, i have tried the sample in this link with same error on Android when calling WLAuthorizationManager.obtainAccessToken() , however it works with iOS

Comment: @VivinK same error with push plugin: com.ibm.mobilefirstplatform.clientsdk.android.push.api.MFPPushException: Response: Status=400, Text: {\"errorCode\":\"invalid_client\",\"errorMsg\":\"Incorrect JWT format\"}, Error Message: Incorrect JWT format"

Comment: On the same device ?Or is this the case across Android devices?

Comment: across android devices

Answer (score 0):

The most common cause of the issue is failure in time synchronization between client and server. Verify if the server time is offset from the client. Specifically if the server has a time in the future.Client has to be synchronized with server time or should be ahead of the server.

Comment: i am getting the same issue.. Is this a reason for the same ? if server is in UAE and we are testing in india.

Comment: Time difference is the most common cause.Verify that first

Comment: Hello @vivin-k, I'm facing with the this problem on IBM Cloud (formerly Bluemix), I already checked client and server clock and seems was synchronized. What else should I take a look?

Comment: @BernardoBaumblatt, can you please tell what happens if you keep the client time slightly ahead? May be 5 minutes ahead of the server.

Comment: @VivinK, sorry the delay on this replay, after upgrade my MFP server (recreate button), the authentication works.